# class << self in ruby and its methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I have a model in ruby on rails with the below code, which uses a singelton class definition. Also, som metaprogramming logic. But, I don't understand when this code will invoke.Is it when an attribute below specified is editing?

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord

    class << self
      ['cat_no', 'effort', 'impact', 'effect', 'feedback'].each do |attr| 
        define_method "update_#{attr}" do |pr, count, user_id|
           pr.order=pr.cat_no     
           pr.idea=pr.description
           pr.update("#{attr}"=>count,:last_modified_by=>user_id)
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: The method should probably be an instance method. (with `pr` being the instance)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code generates five methods, one for each attribute name in the list. All these generated methods take three arguments and will basically look like this (I use the `impact` attribute name as an example):

```
def self.update_impact(pr, count, user_id)
  pr.order = pr.cat_no     
  pr.idea = pr.description
  pr.update("impact" => count, :last_modified_by => user_id)
end
```

That means there are five methods generated that update the passed in `pr` with some data from itself and with a `count` and a `user_id`.

Note that this method only deals with a specific `pr` therefore it is certainly better to use an instance instead of a class method as Stefan already suggested in his comment. And IMO there is not really a benefit in meta-programming here. I would change the logic to

```
def update_count(type, count, user_id) # or any another name that makes sense in the domain
  if type.in?(%i[cat_no effort impact effect feedback])
    update(
      :order => cat_no, 
      :idea => description, 
      :last_modified_by => user_id, 
      type => count
    )
  else
    raise ArgumentError, "unsupported type '#type'"
  end
end
```

and call it instead of

```
Model.update_impact(pr, count, user_id)
```

like this

```
pr.update_count(:impact, count, user_id)
```

Comment: Good answer. I would really use keyword arguments here as there is no natural order to the arguments so its going to b hard to remember what it actually does.